# Global structure of the tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

In differential geometry, when the tangent bundle of a general manifold M is discussed it seems to be discussed only in terms of it’s local aspects. It is usually mentioned that there are no global trivializations and no global sections. Once those disclaimers are given however, most textbooks seem to never mention the global structure again. Is this because there’s nothing important about it or is it that the subject is normally not discussed in more elementary texts?

Comment: Global tangent bundle aspects matter but require advanced tools, so they're often left for later study.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No global sections? Every smooth vector bundle has zillions of sections.

Comment: @TedShifrin But the tangent bundle to a manifold is not in general trivial, no? I may be remembering incorrectly but isn’t a global trivialization necessary for the existence of a global section?

Comment: No, no! Triviality is necessary to have a global *basis* of sections. If you're looking for a single non-vanishing section, you need the Euler class of the oriented vector bundle to vanish.

Comment: @TedShifrin ah, I see where I was wrong. Thanks for your answer